# Why can't I find the MessageBox class in XNA?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I keep reading tutorials of how to use it in Silverlight Apps, but I need it in XNA. All tutorials refer to the package Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices, but there is no such class...

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably not going to want to show the message box class via XNA unless you truly are displaying some type of system type message.

If you're just planning on communicating something via your game to your player, then you'll want to roll your own so you can theme it appropriately to match your game.

Otherwise, the above answer about using GamerServices is correct, that's how you display a MessageBox via XNA but again, you should really restrict your usage of that class for purely system type messages (e.g. "You must be signed in to purchase this game.")

Comment: Okay, so I will have to write my own... -.-

Answer (score 1):

First, check that you have a reference to the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices assembly (in the 'Solution explorer' window, expand 'References'). If you don't, add it (right click on 'References', and click 'Add reference'). Then, you can use `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.Guide.BeginShowMessageBox` to display a message box.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the other suggestions to work for you, I recommend checking out the Game State Management sample.  It has its own message type popup windows.  But more than that, it is a great starting point for any XNA game.

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management